# Export data as PDF Using JQuery In ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, itext

I'm following [C# corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/basic-pdf-export-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc-razor/) article to bind data from controllers action to HTML table and then export data from HTML table to **iTextSharp pdf**. Below i'm binding controllers action method data to html table.

```
@model List<ExportDataAsPDFAppl.Controllers.Employees>  
@using (Html.BeginForm("exportPDF", "Home", FormMethod.Post))  
{  
    <div>  
        <input type="hidden" name="gridHTML" />  
        <input type="submit" id="btnExportHTML" name="btnExportHTML" class="btn btn-success" value="Export Pdf" />  
    </div>  
    <div id="tblEmpData">  
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">  
            <thead>  
                <tr>  
                    <th>ID</th>  
                    <th>FirstName</th>  
                    <th>LastName</th>  
                    <th>Gender</th>  
                    <th>Salary</th>  
                </tr>  
            </thead>  
            <tbody>  
                @foreach (var item in Model)  
                {  
                    <tr>  
                        <td>@item.ID</td>  
                        <td>@item.FirstName</td>  
                        <td>@item.LastName</td>  
                        <td>@item.Gender</td>  
                        <td>@item.Salary</td>  
                    </tr>  
                }  
            </tbody>  
        </table>  
    </div>  
}
```

In `btnExportHTML` jQuery click function, hidden variable `gridHTML` is binded with HTML table.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $('#btnExportHTML').click(function () {  
            debugger;  
            $("input[name='gridHTML']").val($("#tblEmpData").html());  
        });  
    });  
</script>
```

> But on export 'btnExportHTML' click, HTTP 404 error is raised.

Below is action Method for button `btnExportHTML` click.

```
[HttpPost]  
[ValidateInput(false)]  
private FileResult exportPDF(string gridHTML)  
{  
    StringReader reader = null;  
    Document pdfDoc = null;  
    PdfWriter write = null;  
    try  
    {  
        using (MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream())  
        {  
            reader = new StringReader(gridHTML);  
            pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f);  
            write = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memorystream);  
            pdfDoc.Open();  
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(write, pdfDoc, reader);  
            pdfDoc.Close();  
            return File(memorystream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now + ".pdf"));  
        }  

    }  
    finally  
    {  
        reader.Dispose();  
        pdfDoc.Dispose();  
        write.Dispose();  
    }  
}
```

please let me know my mistake to solve this issue.

Comment: Because you method is `private` - make it `public`

Comment: That article was written in 2017. Can you please ask the author why they use iText 5 XMLWorker and don't use IText 7 pdfHTML?

Comment: Thanks for your response @AmedeeVanGasse can you list differences between iText5 & iText7.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke for your response - `public` & `private` make lot of difference :)

Comment: No, I cannot do that within the constraints of a Stack Overflow comment. You will find that information on the iText website: itextpdf.com.